# Unable to change new date format from older one in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

In code I am tried to change new date format from old format but unable to do that it crash and shows "**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**" but I could not found the reason please help to find the reason.

Here I give the code what I am tried..

```
let dateString:String = (historyRequestArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "date") as! String
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
        let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        let finalDateStr:String = dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!)
```

The dateString has value..
**dateString is: 2017-08-02 14:09:22**

Now the current format is : **"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"**

But I want to convert to : **"dd-MMM-yyyy"**

Please help me for to sort out the issue.
Thanks to all.

Comment: seems like current date format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: I think `let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)` fails and when you force unwrap `dateObj` your code crashes.

Comment: i think your dateString will be empty try here if let and check if your dateString is empty or not your code is fine .

Comment: You should use the locale `EN_US_POSIX` when working with a date formatter that is meant to do conversion.

Answer (score 3):

I think your date formatter is wrong, so problem is raised there.

```
let dateString:String = (historyRequestArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "date") as! String
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" //change formatter like this.
let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
let finalDateStr:String = dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!)
```

Comment: @B.SaravanaKumar if You found answer useful you can accept it, so another users can find directly.

Answer (score 2):

Change the date format to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

```
let dateString:String = (historyRequestArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "date") as! String
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
let finalDateStr:String = dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!)
```

Answer (score 1):

some of the date formats are pasted below, where you can change from "hh" to "HH" for hours.
[image]

Hence if you change your code to the following your date formatter will work.

```
let dateString:String = (historyRequestArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "date") as! String
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
let finalDateStr:String = dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!)
```

Comment: Thank you bro for your help.